# The function from the $\{\}$ to an any other set?

Tags: functions, category-theory, definition

In the $\mathcal{SET}$ - category of sets and maps between them - there is an initial object - the $\{\}$. It means that there is **unique** map from the $\{\}$ to an any other set (object of $\mathcal{SET}$).

Not sure I understand it completely. A map $\{\} \mapsto S \in Obj(\mathcal{SET})$ must take some $e \in \{\}$ to a some other $s \in S$. However, **there is no such $e$ by the definition of the empty set**. Thus such function does exist, however **why is it unique**? As long as particular $S$ contains more that one element, there are many maps of $\{\} \mapsto S$ kind. Thus the only way to prove that all those maps are essentially the same is to compare them to each other. In order to run comparsion, one has to kind of "compute" those functions - i.e. to assign some $e \in \{\}$ to each and ensure that outputs $s_0, s_1, ..., s_n \in S$ are the same. Otherwise, how can you determine that abovementioned functions are equal bypassing their evluation?

Comment: There are no elements in the empty set so the only function is the empty function. You can verify for yourself that the empty set is a relation and in fact, is a function. If you are not convinced, try to write down the two functions from the empty set to $S$ that you have in mind.

Comment: Subtle.  A function $f: X \to Y$ must map *every* element of $X$ to an element of $Y$ but that mean it has to map *any* element of $X$ to an element of $Y$.  If $X$ doesn't have any elements then they are all vacuously being mapped to $Y$  (They are also all being sent to Mars on the back of a unicorn made of champagne) without us doing anything.

Comment: If $f:\{0,1,2\}\to \mathbb R; f(x) = x^2$ is the set $\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,4)\} \subset \{0,1\}\times \mathbb R$. then the empty function  $g:\{\}\to Y$ is the set ... $\{\}\subset \{\}\times Y$.  Someone correct me if I am wrong but $\{\}\times Y = \{\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it this way: we say two functions $f$ and $g$ on the same domain are *different* if there exists an $x$ in that domain so that $f(x) \neq g(x)$. In the case where the domain is empty, there obviously cannot be such an $x$, so $f$ and $g$ are automatically not different.

More formally, a function is formally defined as a set of ordered pairs $(e, f(e))$, where $e$ is taken from the domain. If the domain is empty, no such pairs can exist - so any function with domain $\{\}$ must itself be the empty set. And two "copies" of the empty set are automatically equal.

Answer (score 4):

> A map {}↦S∈Obj(SET) must take **some** e∈{} to a some other s∈A (*emphasis mine*)

Not quite.  A map $X\to Y$ must take **every** $e \in X$ to some $s \in Y$.

*Every* does not imply *some*. *some* always means more than $1$.  But if $X = \emptyset$ then *every* means $0$ or none. If there are no $e \in X = \emptyset$ to begin with then *every* element of $\emptyset$ is being mapped to an element of $Y$.  That is because there *aren't* any $e \in X$ so there aren't any $e \in X$ that *aren't* being mapped.  So all of them are being mapped; all $0$ of them.

In the same sense all elements of $\emptyset$ have a first class ticket to Mars on a unicorn made of pink champagne.  And all elements of $\emptyset$ are staying at home playing the tuba.  All elements of $\emptyset$ are doing anything and everything and not doing anything and everything.

This is called vacuous truth.  *Everything* is true about every $e \in \emptyset$ because there aren't an $e \in \emptyset$ so there aren't any cases where it is false.

Okay.... what does this empty $i: \emptyset \to Y$ look like?

Consider a typical function $f: X\to Y$.  Technically $f= \{e\mapsto e_y, d\mapsto d_y,.....\}$ or in other words $f$ is a set of ordered mappings.  An ordered mapping $e\mapsto e_y$ can be written as an ordered pair $(e,e_y)$ so a function $f$ is a set of ordered pairs.

So $f:X\to Y$ is a set $f\subset X\times Y = \{(x,y)|x\in X, y\in Y\}$.  There are some rules.  For every $x \in X$ there is a $y\in Y$ so that $(x,y) \in f$.  And if $(x,y)\in f$ then for any $w \ne y$ then $(x,y)\not \in f$.  But those rules aren't important right now.  The important thing now is $f \subset X\times Y$.

That's what a function "really" is. You can think of it as some kind of rule, or a little box with a handle that when you put in input output comes out, or some little monster with a pointing tail.  But what it technically is is a set of ordered pairs.  (All these interpretations are compatible.)

So what is $\emptyset\times Y$?  Well, it is $\{(x,y)|x\in \emptyset, y\in Y\}$ but as there are no $x \in \emptyset$: $\emptyset\times Y=\{(x,y)|x\in \emptyset, y\in Y\}=\emptyset$

So $i:\emptyset \to Y$ is simply... an emptyset of zero ordered pairs.

One way to think about it is... the empty function just is.  It maps *nothing* to anything you want and you don't have to do anything to have it happen.

In a way, it's useless because *nothing* can be afffected or mapped by it.  But logically from a constructivist point of view we must build everything up from nothing and a foundation for all objects must be an empty object.  So we must start with an empty function that... does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Functions from $A$ to $B$ are subsets of $A\times B$. In particular they are sets. The only function from $\emptyset$ to any other set $S$ is the empty function $\emptyset\subset\emptyset\times S$.

*Warning: opinionated!* (read comments below)

More strikingly, there isn't just one function for every $S$, it is also the same for all $S$!

Comment: That last statement is false, for a function is a  *triple* $(D, C, R)$, where $R \subset D \times C$ is a subset with certain properties. The empty function to $S$ is $(\emptyset, S, \emptyset)$, while the empty function with codomain $T$ is $(\emptyset, T, \emptyset)$. These are the same only if $S = T$.

Comment: @JohnHughes I think it's debatable. A function can be just the relation. Some relations are symmetric, some transitive, some total, etc... Some of them are functions.

Comment: If the function is just the relation, how can one possibly tell whether it's surjective? The question doesn't even make sense. It's true that the domain is a redundant member of the triple, and one could define a function as a pair $(C, R)$, and let $D = \pi_1(R)$ be the result of projecting on the first factor, but I don't think anyone does that, because it makes the definition read much less fluidly. I have to admit that some authors (even Halmos, whose approaches I generally like) say that a function is just the relation, (as in his Naive Set Theory). But then he cannot talk of f being ...

Comment: I still think this is very philosophical. You can read for instance https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Function, where they take a position even more extreme than mine. They don't even require the relation to be left-total, meaning that the domain can be a subset of your $D$.

Comment: ...surjective or injective, and instead must use phrases like "$f$ maps $X$ **onto** $Y$" rather than "into $Y$." The inability to ascribe properties to higher-level constructs like functions seems like too great a price to pay (to me).  I think this may be a topologists-vs-logicians kind of distinction.

Comment: This point of view is sustainable, in the sense that you can say that a function is surjective when viewed in the context of a domain $X$ and codomain $Y$.

Comment: But again, I think all of this is quite pointless

Comment: I completely agree with your position, but at the same time I don't reject the other one.

Comment: What you say about higher level constructs is true, but at the same time you lose something else: the functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb N$ and $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for every $x$ are now different. Is this something you prefer? I personally think that both approaches have different pros and cons. That's why I don't stick to one in particular, but instead choose which one is more convenient every time, knowing that in the end they are equivalent.

Comment: I could rephrase my last sentence in the answer as follows: "More strikingly, the underlying relation associated to the (unique) function $\emptyset\to S$ is unique for all $S$!". Seems a bit convoluted

Comment: I agree that they're different, and regard that as a virtue. Swap things around to $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ vs $g: \Bbb  N \to \Bbb N$, where $f(n) = g(n) = n$, and one is surjective and the other is not. I too see the value of the "relation only" view ... but not to me as a practicing mathematician (and certainly not to me as a practicing computer scientist!)

Comment: Well, the relational approach should be appealing to programmers preferring weakly typed languages

Comment: Indeed. That's consistent with my statement that it's of no use to **me** as a practicing computer scientist. :)

Comment: Also a lot of people like to say $\Delta:H^1(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ with domain $D(\Delta)$. In the end, it's clear what they mean, so I don't see the problem

Comment: Yeah, I understand, Haskell is not very weakly typed :D
Oh wait, that is another John Hughes!

Comment: Indeed. I keep dreaming of someday writing a paper with him!

Comment: And also, according to your definition, how can you give to students exercises of the type "Determine the domain of the function $f(x)=\frac1{1-x^2}$"? In order to give them the function, you need to provide also the solution! :D